# Designing Flexible SQL Schema [for Quests]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What would be an efficient way to store "Quests" in an SQL database? Let's say the context is RPG. (Here was a previous question: [How to store Goals (think RPG Quest) in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672206/how-to-store-goals-think-rpg-quest-in-sql))

To summarize a Quest may be a combination of the following:

```
Discover [Location]
Kill n [MOB Type]
Acquire n of [Object]
Achieve a [Skill] in [Skillset]
All the other things you get in RPGs
```

The answer listed out in the link was:

For the Quest table:

```
| ID | Title | FirstStep (Foreign key to GuestStep table) | etc.
```

The QuestStep table

```
| ID | Title | Goal (Foreign key to Goal table) | NextStep (ID of next QuestStep)
```

I actually think it's pretty neat, but I have two things I would like to add:

Let's say I want to create it so that a quest can only be active only on certain days (e.g. M W F only) and/or active only at a certain time span (e.g. Halloween). What would be the ideal way of doing this?

Another thing: Let say I want to have a quest with two steps and a quest with 8 steps. We can create a table that is 8 columns wide but we would have lots of empty space. And what if the stars align and I needed an 9 *step-wide* quest?

The QuestStep table actually has a NextStep, sort of like a linked list, but what about Quests that you can do out of order?

P.S: As you can see it is potentially read-heavy, and the schema is potentially... non-schematic. Is NosSQL a vying option? (Redis seems memory only, so I'll more likely go with MongoDB)

Comment: How many quests are you planning on storing in this way? If we're only talking hundreds or maybe a few thousand quests, a better approach might be to not store them in a relational database format at all, but instead using any kind of serialization that supports references (for linked lists, etc.). XML for example.

Comment: @Dan Would this be alright read-performance-ly (such a word exists I think) speaking?

Comment: Well, as long as we're talking at most a few thousand quests (or maybe even tens of thousands, depending on the amount of data used to represent each quest), you might as well keep everything in your application servers memory and then only do writes when things change. You will need a mechanism to read everything from disk, but that is something you will only have to do once, when your application starts. You won't get better performance than this. However, if you're planning on distributing the application across multiple servers, that might be an entirely different issue...